# Is it possible to design like three layouts in iOS devices (both iPhone and iPad also)like in the attached picture (for reference see the pic.)?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, user-interface, ipad

[image]
Three Column(i.e Three Table Views in each Column) UI Design View.

1. To design the UI on the both iPhone and iPad is possible like 3 column of different tableviews
2. And among all of columns there is also need interaction like when ever one cell selected in the first tableview then corresponding cell details need to display in the middle table view.(Like Split View Controller.)
3. And, finally in third table view controller need to display some retailer names too.

Comment: Yes, probably, but your picture shows an empty storyboard scene.

Comment: Actually, screen shot itself like three table views inside one view controller like left panel one table view, middle editor like one more table view and right panel like one another table view, but finally i need to put all 3 in 1 controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create as shown in the [iProSoccer](http://iprosoccer.com) app screenshot below. Selecting a plan on left table shows the drills in the middle column. The right column contains the available drills that can be dragged into a plan (middle column). This is a single view controller containing three table controllers added as child view controllers.

[image]

**EDIT**

Each of the `UITableViewController`'s defines a `protocol` and delegate the containing `UIViewController` subscribes to. When an action by the user, for example, tapping a plan in the left table view, the left table view controller tells (sends a message to) the delegate (the containing `UIViewController`). In this example the message includes the plan that was selected. The containing `UIViewController` updates the center `UITableViewController` with the plan. The center `UITableViewController` then loads the details of the plan.

Snippet of (the child) PlanTableViewController.h including protocol and delegate definition:

```
#import "Plan.h"

@class PlanTableViewController;

@protocol PlanTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)planSelected:(Plan *)plan sender:(id)sender;

    // Additional protocol methods here...

@end

@interface PlanTableViewController : UITableViewController 

@property (nonatomic, weak)id <PlanTableViewControllerDelegate>delegate;

    // Additional properties and methods here...

@end
```

Snippet of (the parent) PlanningTableViewController.m including the implementation of the delegate method:

```
@interface PlanningTableViewController () {

    PlanTableViewController *planTableViewController;

    // Additional properties declarations here...

@end

@implementation PlanningTableViewController 


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    planTableViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"planTableViewController"];
    planTableViewController.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - PlanTableViewController delegate methods

- (void)planSelected:(Plan *)plan sender:(id)sender {

    [drillTableViewController planSelected:plan];
}

// Additional delegate methods here...

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, but syncing among all table views how to implement in iOS and Objective C